File upload from azure app service to file share is very slow
So I have this setup:

a blazor web app project
.net 8
hostested in Azure app service with the Standard S1 tier.
a storage account from where I use file share to maintain documents from the app.

What I am trying to do?
I am trying to upload files from the blazor app to the file share.(I make a transition from web forms to blazor and file shares is already there so I cannot use something else).
Problem and what I tried so far
When I upload files from the application hosted in azure, the upload takes over 70 seconds for a 15MB pdf. This should be done faster as the user will have a problem with this.
What could be the problem?
So far I tried multiple solution(for each solution the upload from my local machine works fast as I would like to be, so from this I suppose that the problem comes from azure app service somehow).
For each of the solutions presented below I also tried different app service plans. Standard S2 and all the premiums ones.
Solution 1:
I tried to mount the file share in the app service. It uploads but it takes very long time.
Solutions 2:
I tried using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares to upload directly to the file
 using var fileStream = fileUpload.File.OpenReadStream(long.MaxValue); // Limit max size to handle larger files if needed


      long fileSize = fileStream.Length;
      const int chunkSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4MB per chunk
      await fileClient.CreateAsync(fileSize);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
        long offset = 0;

        // Store the tasks for parallel execution
        var uploadTasks = new List<Task>();

        while (offset < fileSize)
        {

            int bytesRead = await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Copy the data to avoid threading issues
            var chunkData = new byte[bytesRead];
            Array.Copy(buffer, 0, chunkData, 0, bytesRead);
            long currentOffset = offset;

            // Create and store the upload task
            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(chunkData))
                {
                    await fileClient.UploadRangeAsync(new HttpRange(currentOffset, bytesRead), memoryStream);
                }
                //progressCallback(currentOffset + bytesRead, fileSize);
            });

            uploadTasks.Add(task); // Add the task to the list
            offset += bytesRead; // Move the offset forward
        }

        // Wait for all upload tasks to finish
        await Task.WhenAll(uploadTasks);

Solution 3: I tried Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement which I read that this package is desined for blobs and for large files. I managed to point it to my file share and upload file but the same problem.
 CloudFile fileReference = uploadFileLocal.GetFileReference(fileUpload.File.Name.Trim())

 var transferContext = new SingleTransferContext
 {
     ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>(progress =>
     {
         progressCallback(progress.BytesTransferred, fileUpload.File.Size);
     })
 };

 // Perform the upload using DMLib
 // await TransferManager.UploadAsync(tempFilePath, fileReference, null, transferContext);
 using (var stream = fileUpload.File.OpenReadStream(104857600))
 {
     // Perform the upload using DMLib
     await TransferManager.UploadAsync(stream, fileReference, null, transferContext);
 }

I also tried to save the file to the disk first and there I noticed that the disk upload took over 70 seconds and after the upload to file share took 2 seconds.. When uploading I would have given the file path await
TransferManager.UploadAsync(tempFilePath, fileReference, null, transferContext);

Nothing is working. What can I do?

Try with premium tier refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1665497/problem-with-network-bandwidth-of-azure-app-servic

I tried with all the premium version and the result is the same.

I suggest you could try this article  mounted the Azure file share to the Azure web app. Then directly upload to that file path instead of using the storage package.
